# Spring Web Sockets - Get access to web socket session in controller

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, websocket, spring-websocket

I am working on a spring web socket app and I am looking to find a way to get hold of the spring web socket session decorator at my controller.

By looking at the spring code I saw that WebSocketSessions by default are decorated with ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator in SubProtocolWebSocketHandler:decorateSession()

Here is how my code looks like

```
@Controller
public class MyController {


   @MessageMapping("/endpoint")
    public void method(Request request) {
        //logic
        // This is where I want to have access to ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator 
    }
}
```

Is it possible to get access to the decorator in my controller ?

Thanks

Nikos

Comment: what if you inject the `ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator` in your method ?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a bean

Comment: No but I mean in the same way as you inject the request ? `public void method(ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator request) {` Even if it is not a `bean` it can be injected by Spring sometimes (like `Principal`, or `HttpRequest`...)

Comment: tried that but it is not injected by spring